# every function in $C^k_0(U)$ is $C^k_0(\mathbb{R}^d)$

Tags: functional-analysis

Often in many proofs we treat functions in $C^k_0(U)$ (the set of $C^k$ functions with compact support where $U$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^d$) as functions in $C^k_0(\mathbb{R}^d)$.They extend it by zero without saying why this new function if of compact support.
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{\supp}{\operatorname{supp}}
\begin{align}
C^k_0 &=\{f\in C^k(U):\: \supp(f) \text{ is compact }\} \\
\supp(f) & =\overline{\{x\in U,f(x)\neq 0\}}
\end{align}
$$
Here are my questions that might help me understand. I

1. Is the closure in the definition of the support taken relatively to $\mathbb{R}^d$ topology, or to the induced topology over $U$?
2. Is it true that $\supp(f)$ need not to be closed in $\mathbb{R}^d$  if it is taken relatively to the subspace topology, because
   $$
   \supp(f)=\overline{\{x\in U,f(x)\neq 0\}}^{\,U}=\overline{\{x\in U,f(x)\neq 0\}}^{\,\mathbb{R}^d}\cap U
   $$
   and if we take the colsure in $\mathbb{R}^d$ then $\supp(f)$ might be going outside $U$?

Thank you.

Comment: Where do you see the definition of $C_0^k(U)$? The usual version requires that the support is not only compact but also *contained* in $U$. See for instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Definitions_of_test_functions_and_distributions

Comment: If i understand right 
$supp(f)=\overline{\{x\in U,f(x)\}}^{\mathbb{R}^d}$ and $C^k_0(U)=\{f\in C^k(U)\text{ and }supp(f) \text{is compact}\subset U\}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it's impossible for the support to go outside $U$ in either case, if $U$ is open and the support is assumed compact. If a function $f$ has compact support $K = \text{supp}(f)$ in $U$ then the distance from $K$ to $\partial U$ is strictly positive. This is because, viewed as subsets of $\mathbb{R}^d$, $K$ compact, $\partial U$ closed implies the distance between the two sets is attained by some $p \in K, q \in \partial U$. If the distance were zero, then $p = q$ and $K \cap \partial U \neq \emptyset$. But as $K \subset U$, where $U$ is open, this says that $U \cap \partial U \neq \emptyset$, a contradiction (open sets don't intersect their boundaries). Therefore the distance from $K$ to $\partial U$ is strictly positive. It follows from this that compactness of the support in $U$ under the subspace topology is equivalent to compactness of the support in the topology of $\mathbb{R}^d$ (I think this also follows from general topological arguments). As you point out, this is not true for closedness of the support. This is one indication that compactness is stronger/more important in some senses than closure.

Comment: Let $U=]-1,1[$ and $f:U\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $V=\{x\in U,f(x)\neq 0\}=]0,1[$. If we define the support of $f$ to be the closure of V in $\mathbb{R}^1$ 
then $supp(f)=\overline{V}=[0,1]$ and its going outside of $U$!!

Comment: Yes, this is true - but I assumed that $f$ had compact support in $U$. In this case your example $f$ doesn't have compact support in $U$. (The analogous statement is not true for "closed" support, as your example shows.)